# Why is my alias command doing nothing?

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, alias, tcsh

It's not that trying to run the alias doesn't do what I expect. The alias command itself appears to do nothing.

If I try to do:

```
alias python2='python3'
alias | grep python
```

I get two blank outputs. I would expect the second to acknowledge that I had added an alias, but it does not.

Comment: based on what you describe, it should work as you expect. what happens if you run `alias` without the grep? is the shell you are in your own, or is it perhaps sudo'd/su'd?

Comment: alias by itself gives me a list of what appear to be pretty conventional aliases. One example is grep    grep --color=auto. Another is ll    ls -l --color=auto. It should be my own shell.

Comment: Try to alias the full path of python3. Does the command `python3` work by itself?

Comment: python3 works. I tried aliasing to the full path, and I'm seeing the same behavior.